# SQL - Query everything but

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table of products. Some products share products keys. For example there are multiple bikes with the product id of 1, but there are different versions of the bikes. So two records can both have id of 1, but they have different version Id's like 1-15. What I'm trying to do is query the table to get all the matching version ids that have the value of 12 but not the value of 13 (because some versions from 12 are already listed as 13 as well, but i want to remove the remaining 12's to 13) . Basically a join where the products keys dont match. What is the best way to do this. I was thinking of an inner join, but it is returning duplicates for some reason. Can anyone help me out?

```
select *  from products as tbl_1
full outer join products as tbl_2 
on tbl_1.p_id = tbl_2.p_id 
where tbl_1.p_version = '12' and tbl_2.p_version = '13'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.p_id
from products p
where p_version in (12, 13)
group by p.p_id
having max(p_version) = 12;
```

You can also do this with a `join`, if you like:

```
select p12.*
from products p12 left join
     products p13
     on p12.p_id = p13.p_id and p13.p_version = 13
where p12.p_version = 12 and p13.p_id is null;
```

Or, you could use `not exists` or `not in`.  I find the aggregation approach to be the most flexible.

Comment: where the product keys dont match.  I want all the products for version 12, that are not in version 13 already

Comment: @John . . . I do think this query does what you want.  There is no matching key to `p13` -- for instance -- if a product has no version 13.

Answer (score 0):

Use Except:

```
select p.id
from products p
where p.version_id = 12
except
select p.id
from products p
where p.version_id = 13
```

Comment: where the product keys dont match

Comment: This will return all the products that have a version of 12 but don't have a version of 13.

Comment: For me it returns the same amount of records as a select * where  = 12. The number should be less since some of the values from13 are sahred with 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
DECLARE @products table (p_id int , p_version int)

INSERT @products values
 ( 1,12)
,( 1,13)
,( 2,12)
,( 3,11) 
,( 4,12) 
,( 5,10) 
,( 6,14) 
,( 7,11) 
(8 row(s) affected)

Select p.p_id
from @products p
where p_version = 12 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  From @products p2 where 
p.p_id = p2.p_id and p2.p_version = 13)


(4 row(s) affected)
p_id
-----------
2
4
(2 row(s) affected)
```

except works too, As mentioned by @cloudsafe

```
select p.p_id
from @products p
where p.p_version = 12
except
select p.p_id
from @products p
where p.p_version = 13
    p_id
    -----------
    2
    4
    (2 row(s) affected)
```